# jQuery clone does not clone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
</div>
```

with:

```
$('.spacer').clone().appendTo('.header')
```

But this **moves** `.spacer`element to `.header` element, instead if **copying** it.

I don't understand why this does not work, because in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) says that:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

is converted to:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">
    Goodbye
    <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with `$('.hello').clone().appendTo('.goodbye');`

Any ideas?

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jVpHh/).

1. Orange is where I want to paste items
2. Yellow is the spacer
3. Items I want to paste are in different colors
4. Red at the bottom is where I am fetching the clones

Comment: show your html containing spacer class

Comment: The code you have shown [should work](http://jsbin.com/aguyiv/1/); try to create a reproducible piece of code.

Comment: Please add a jsFiddle for your code.

Comment: Works just fine for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kySgS/)

Comment: My fiddle also works ok ;) http://jsfiddle.net/KNxwC/ Maybe something is wrong with jQuery library you are using

Comment: Yes is working in Fiddle... I would have to copy paste more code from my application, but could it be caused by coffeescript?

Comment: Don't know anything about coffeecrap, but it's more likely caused by "developer error" ?

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't contain any coffeescript, which is also why I removed the tag.

Comment: You are right is not should not be tagged coffeescript

Comment: I tested with jQuery from the official page but same result

Comment: Please delete this question as it won't help future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have debugged with fiddle, thanks. I found a div that I was not closing.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your code is inside `document.ready`. It specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded. Looks like your function was called before the dom is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.spacer').clone().appendTo('.header');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You might forgot the semicolon ";" as this is working:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.spacer').clone().appendTo('.header');
 });
```